# How do calculate which RAM option would be faster?

Tags: memory, performance, data-transfer, ddr2, dual-channel

I've been reading DDR and related info on wikipedia but am still not sure I know anything.

I have a Fujitsu Celsius w340 workstation with the following:

- Memory Speed: 533 MHz
- Memory Specification Compliance: PC2-4300
- Dual Channel
- Configuration Features: 2 x 512 MB

I have 2 x 512MB PC2-3200 sticks (which is what it came with) and I have a stick of 2GB PC2-6400.

Now I've replaced the two sticks with the one so that I have 2GB to run windows 7 and there's not really a problem. But in future I would like to know what I'm doing so I have to ask and can't figure it out.

**Which is faster?**

There doesn't seem to be any information on what "Memory Specification Compliance" is.

I also can't figure out if "Memory Speed" is the memory clock or the I/O bus clock, and I would be lying if I said I know exactly what either of those are. Is the I/O clock the FSB and is that what "Memory Speed" of the motherboard referring to?

And does the fact that my Windows7 installation is 32bit matter?

I know the PC2-6400 is theoretically twice as fast as PC2-3200 but would the 6400 be operating at it's full potential or would the advantage of Dual Channel on the two 3200 sticks outperform it?

Answer (score 2):

I would be much more concerned about the capacity than the speed with regards to 2GB of RAM.

Programs are gobbling up more and more RAM these days - `Chrome/Chromium` can use up to **1GB** per tab (and I've heard of the browser using **5GB** with only one tab open!). **8GB** is the new standard, wasn't that long ago **512MB** was.

Filling up your RAM leads to *swapping to disk* (pagefile on Windows) which slows processes down significantly and in some cases (if the "hand-off" isn't done in time) the system will become so unresponsive it will "freeze".

Versions of Windows that are 32-bit can support up to **~3.3GB** of RAM; 32-bit Linux distros with a PAE-enabled kernel can support 64GB.

Since you mentioned **future**, starting with [some] Nehalem (i3/i5/i7) generation CPUs and newer, Intel replaced the *Front-Side Bus* with the *QuickPath Interconnect* which among other things means the memory controller is on the processor in modern CPUs rather than the motherboard. This means the bottleneck is the CPU instead of the motherboard chipset (though it is still a factor) with regards to the memory speeds possible.

Comment: Nice answer. But 1GB+ per tab sounds unreal, where did you find that info?